# Is Levi Ackerman of Asian descent, like Mikasa?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I don't think its ever mentioned if Levi is of Asian descent like Mikasa or not, and if it was I completely missed it.

Is Levi of Asian descent?

Answer (score 7):

He is not. Ackerman and Asians are unrelated. Mikasa is Asian from her mother's side and Ackerman from her father.

Answer (score 4):

Mikasa's partially Asian because of [her mother](https://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Mikasa%27s_mother), who was part of the [Azumabito family](https://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Azumabito_family), the family that's known as the "Asian clan inside the Walls". On her father's side she belongs to the [Ackerman family](https://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Ackerman_family), just like Levi on his mother's side.

While we don't know anything about Levi's father, it's highly unlikely that he would also be a member of the sole Asian family that exists inside the wall.

Comment: This answer is kind of incorrect. The "Asian clan inside the walls" are also Eldian, because they live in Eldia, the country where Attack on Titan takes place. The Ackermans are a different ethnic group, however.

Comment: @Kai I've taken that line directly from the wiki - hence the quotation marks. But looks like I misunderstood the part about Eldians, I'll touch up my aswer.